# UIAlertControllerの使い方

Tags: swift

iOSのapp開発において結果として
UIAlertControllerを頻繁に使ってしまいました。
（極端な話、Viewを遷移するたびに使うたびに表示）

ウル覚えなのですが、頻繁にUIAlertを使用するアプリはリジェクト
対象だったのではないでしょうか？

iOS Human Interface Guidelines
やネットでざっと探してみたところ、
現在はリジェクト理由にないようですが、
どなたか詳し方がいましたら、アドバイスいただければ幸いです。

＜追記：2015/4/20＞
iOS Human Interface Guidelines
[一時ビュー](https://developer.apple.com/jp/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Alerts/Alerts.html)に不要なアラートを作成しない。一般に、次のような場合には不要です」
ここの記述に引っかかるのではないかと心配です。

Answer (score 2):

（リジェクトの話なので、あくまで私の１見解として聞き流してください。）

UIAlertを使用しすぎた結果リジェクトされたという例はないので、使いすぎでも基本的には気にしないでいいと思います。

もしも引っかかるとしたら、

> 10.6 – Apple and our customers place a high value on simple, refined, creative, well thought through interfaces. They take more work but are worth it. Apple sets a high bar. If your user interface is complex or less than very good, it may be rejected
>
> Appleと顧客は簡潔で扱いやすく、上品で、創造的な洗練されたインターフェースを好みます。それは多くの手間がかかりますが、それだけの価値があります。Appleは高いバーを設定します。もしあなたのユーザーインターフェースが複雑だったり、洗練されていないアプリはリジェクト。
>
> ### http://lab.sonicmoov.com/smartphone/reasons-of-iphone-app-rejects/

この理由が該当するのではないかと思われます。